# Unable to build jquery with grunt - submodule error

Tags: jquery, build, gruntjs

I have no luck building the jQuery (git) using grunt.

Everything went smoothly till the actual grunt command which outputs as following:

```
grunt --config Gruntfile.js 

Running "update_submodules" task

TypeError: Cannot call method 'spawn' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/maciejbodek/Dropbox/Htdocs/git/jquery/node_modules/grunt-update-submodules/tasks/update-submodules.js:7:14)
at Object.task.registerTask.thisTask.fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:58:16)
at Task.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:343:36)
at Task.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:359:5)
at Object.grunt.tasks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:143:8)
at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:36:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt:19:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Any hints appreciated. Installed all the needed npm dependiences and so on. It's just the build process that ends up being aborted.

Comment: It looks like you might be using the wrong version of grunt. What version of grunt do you have installed globally? If it's grunt 0.3.x, then you won't be able to run that Gruntfile (which appears to be grunt-0.4.x Gruntfile.js).

Comment: @smithclay yeah, I was running 0.3.17. Silly question - how do I update to the latest devel (0.4.x)? `npm install grunt@0.4` seems to work and yet I get 0.3 as an output to `grunt --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run latest dev version of grunt, which you can get with `npm install grunt@master`

Also make sure you have uninstalled the old global grunt `npm uninstall -g grunt` and installed grunt-cli globally `npm install -g grunt-cli`.

See [Upgrading from 0.3 to 0.4](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4)

Comment: This doesn't work for building jQuery 1.9.0b1, which I'm trying to do.  At the very least, that jQuery 1.9.0b1 has grunt.js files rather than Gruntfile.js files, so is clearly designed to work with grunt v0.3 rather 0.4.  FWIW, I can't build jQuery 2.0.0b1 with grunt 0.4 either, but that's a separate problem.