# grunt.js grunt-init issue

Tags: javascript, shell, gruntjs

I recently moved to grunt-cli and ditched global grunt v0.3.x.  I'm trying to install grunt-init globally and ran into an issue where it wasn't being added to the PATH because of the missing bin file or what have you, so I found issue 29 in the github repo issue tracker (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init/issues/29), uninstalled grunt-init, ran npm cache clear and reinstalled grunt-init@0.2.0rc3 so the shell is at least recognizing the grunt-init command, but not when I try to run grunt-init --help (or any other grunt-init command) I get a fatal error

```
$ grunt-init --help
Fatal error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

or trying to scaffold a template

```
$ grunt-init gruntfile
Running "init:gruntfile" (init) task
Warning: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any ideas?

grunt version

```
$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.6
```

and Grunt Init version

```
$ grunt-init --version
grunt-init v0.2.0rc3
grunt v0.4.0rc5
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254967/unable-to-build-jquery-with-grunt-submodule-error

Comment: Yeah, tried all that.  I'm having trouble just running grunt-init on an empty directory, just throws an error.  I can't even get grunt-init --help to run with it throwing this error:  Fatal error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Comment: It's related to a recent file api change introduced in grunt-0.4.0rc5. It the list of contrib projects that have been updated to work with grunt-0.4.0rc5, I don't see any updates to grunt-init (yet): https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/606.